# AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'public_blob'

Tags: python, ssh, paramiko

I'd like to get a file onto my raspberry pi from my google cloud compute engine, but I get the following error:

```
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/paramiko/auth_handler.py", line 212, in wait_for_response
raise e
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'public_blob'
```

What does this error message mean?

Thanks in advance!

python file:

```
import paramiko

hostname = '43.123.231.212'
password = 'passw'
username = 'dosop'
port = 22

gc_path='/home/do//assets/locations.txt'
remotepath='/home/pi/ada.txt'

t = paramiko.Transport((hostname, 22))
t.connect(username=username, password=password, pkey="/home/pi/dos/priv_key"
sftp = paramiko.SFTPClient.from_transport(t)
sftp.get(gc_path, remotepath)
```

Comment: It basically fails when trying to authenticate, your pass or private key must be wrong

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. In what form should I give the private key to the pkey variable? As a string or as a file?

Comment: @Marci, try `pk = paramiko.RSAKey.from_private_key(open("/home/pi/dos/priv_key")‌​); t.connect(username=username, password=password, pkey=pk)`. You need to actually create a PKey object to pass to the pkey parameter.

Comment: paramiko.ssh_exception.PasswordRequiredException: Private key file is encrypted

Comment: Your private key file has a password/passcode. Assuming you know what it is, you should provide this password as a second argument to the `paramiko.RSAKey.from_private_key` function.

Comment: okay, it's perfect, thank you!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The parameter `pkey`, much like `hostkey`, expects a value of type `PKey`. But you seem to be providing a string to it. You can get a `PKey` object out of your private key file by creating an object from `paramiko.RSAKey`. The following should help:

```
import paramiko

hostname = '43.123.231.212'
password = 'passw'
username = 'dosop'
port = 22

gc_path='/home/do//assets/locations.txt'
remotepath='/home/pi/ada.txt'
pk = paramiko.RSAKey.from_private_key(open('/home/pi/dos/priv_key'))
t = paramiko.Transport((hostname, 22))
t.connect(username=username, password=password, pkey=pk)
sftp = paramiko.SFTPClient.from_transport(t)
sftp.get(gc_path, remotepath)
```

Please note that this assumes you're working with `rsa` keys; hence the use of `paramiko.RSAKey`.

Also, please keep in mind that if your private key file has a password, you will need to provide the password as a second argument to the function `paramiko.RSAKey.from_private_key`, like the following:

```
pk = paramiko.RSAKey.from_private_key(open('/home/pi/dos/priv_key'), 'password')
```

I hope this helps.